# При открытии галереи, переходить на картинку, с которой был переход на страницу галереи

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая вообще должна быть логика данного процесса.
Есть страница с галереей, на где фотографии просто выводятся "плиткой" и при нажатии увеличиваются:

```
<li>
<a href="ссылка на 2галерею" data-largesrc="большая картинка" data-title="1146" data-description="">
<img src="маленькая картинка"/>
<p class="article">1146</p>
</a>
</li>
```

2 галерея представляет собой более удобный просмотр огромных картинок.

```
<li>
<a href="#">
<img src="миниатюра" data-large="огромная картинка" data-description="1146" /></a>    
</li>
```

В 1 галереи, при нажатии на маленькую картинку раскрывается окошко с большой картинкой(аля гугл), а рядом стоит ссылка "просмотреть в формате галереи". И нужно, чтобы при нажатии этой ссылки, открывалась 2галерея уже на той картинке, с которой был сделан переход, ибо там пару сотен фотографий, и искать желаемое в этой куче как-то не очень.
з.ы.: я не прошу написать вместо меня код, подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом это вообще можно реализовать.

Comment: надо найти смещение по вертикали(?) картинки во второй галерее и установить позицию скролла на это значение.

Comment: хорошо, я могу указать конкретное смещение скролла, но нужно ведь еще открыть нужную фотку

Comment: в смысле открыть ? в общем давайте больше кода. ваша задача не ясна и по моему слишком усложнена.

Comment: вот 1 галерея
http://xvision.com.ua/main/ukrchic/весільні-сукні/показ-1/
вот 2
http://xvision.com.ua/main/ukrchic/весільні-сукні/галерея-укршик/

при нажатии на фотографию на 1, открывается ее увеличиная копия, где есть ссылка на переход в режим галереи. И нужно сделать, чтобы 2 галерея открывалась именно на той фотографии, с которой был сделан переход. з.ы.: извините, что мудрю, просто не знаю где копать даже

Comment: вам надо перед переходом по ссылке запомнить что за картинка была выбрана, можно использовать для этого библиотечка jStorage, потом на новой странице взять имя картинки которую надо открыть и просто вызвать "click" по ней (ну и проскроллить туда можно)

Comment: спасибо, добрый человек